# How to parse web address into clickable link

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a way to take the text from a TextInputEditText and if there are any links in it amongst the text, parse the links into clickable links?

Example text: "Hi. This is Brent and this is my website: www.mywebsite.com."
I only want "www.mywebsite.com" a clickable link. Now, some users would put the http://
in front too.  That should also be linked if present.

I've tried using:
`tv_bio.setText(Html.fromHtml(Globals.PublicProfileUserData.getBio(),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));`

However, it only parses links if used within an HREF HTML tag.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using autolink="web" did the trick.

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_public_profile_bio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
         />
```

It parses web links with: http://, https://, www, or no www.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a *regular expression pattern* to identify matching text.

The RFC for *URL* defines a syntax in *[ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)* which can be translated to a *regex pattern*.
*[RFC 1738 – Uniform Resource Locators (URL) – BNF for specific URL schemes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#autoid-33)*

```
hostname       = *[ domainlabel "." ] toplabel
domainlabel    = alphadigit | alphadigit *[ alphadigit | "-" ] alphadigit
toplabel       = alpha | alpha *[ alphadigit | "-" ] alphadigit
```

```
(?:https?://)?(?i)(?:(?:[a-z\d]+|[a-z\d][a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])\.)+(?:[a-z]+|[a-z][a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])
```

And, the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes can be used to apply the *pattern*.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
s.append("Hi. This is Brent and this is my website: www.mywebsite.com.");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:https?://)?(?i)(?:(?:[a-z\\d]+|[a-z\\d][a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])\\.)+(?:[a-z]+|[a-z][a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    s.replace(m.start(), m.end(), "<a href=\"%s\">%1$s</a>".formatted(m.group()));
```

Output

```
Hi. This is Brent and this is my website: <a href="www.mywebsite.com">www.mywebsite.com</a>.
```

Comment: I will check out this option in the morning and report back here tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

if you want to highlight links

```
val WEB_LINK_REGEX_STRING = PatternsCompat.WEB_URL.toString()

fun TextView.highlightLinks() {
    Linkify.addLinks(this, Pattern.compile(WEB_LINK_REGEX_STRING), null)
}
```

and then

```
tv_bio.setText(text)
tv_bio.highlightLinks()
```

Comment: I will try this option in the morning and report back here